# Don't include the username as a part of the candidate statement

Tags: feature-request, design, election, responsive-design

The candidate statement on the moderator election page contains the username of the candidate as a header part of it by default. You can manually remove it, but almost nobody does it. For instance, look at [nomnoms12's candidate statement](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=election#post-1510788). On the full size page mode that looks fine:

> [image: nomnoms12 full size]

But if you open it in narrow width mode, you will see the following:

> [image: nomnoms12 narrow size]

As you can see, the username is doubled. That's because the top one is generated by the site engine (actual username), and the bottom one is taken from the candidate statement.

To make both versions (full site and narrow mode) uniform in that part, **I suggest removing the auto-added header part from the candidate statement** (e.g., as it was three years ago), and adding the title (user name) by engine on full site mode as well.

For instance, [my own candidate statement](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=election#post-1511549) doesn't have a header part (I removed it manually), and that's how it looks in full site mode:

> [image: my statement full site]

Without a header/title it is hard to understand if it's the beginning of another candidate statement or not.

In narrow mode, the statement looks better, since there isn't any username duplication:

> [image: my statement narrow mode]

Comment: Can't reproduce, I see one name.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard could you pleaee add a screenshot?

Comment: @Shadow Adjust the width of your browser's window, when it's narrow it duplicates the username.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace well, no way to guess such thing. Though OP always using only very narrow screen (Probably on purpose to find bugs) but still, my "default" is what I use, which is standard screen. (Not very big)

Comment: @Shadow "no way to guess such thing"? The question states "if you open it in narrow width mode [...]"

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard do you ever use responsive mode, I mean use the SE sites from mobile devices like phone/tablet?